# Array declared in config file does not reflect changes after config:clear in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **constants** file located in `\config\constants.php` and it's an array of all the constants I am using in my project.

Sample declaration of the array in the file:

```
return [
'contant_1' => [
    'value_1' => 'a',
    'value_2' => 'b',
    'value_3' => 'c'
],
'constant_2' => [
    'value_1' => 'd',
    'value_2' => 'e',
    'value_3' => 'f'
],
'constant_3' => [
    'value_1' => 'g',
    'value_2' => 'h',
    'value_3' => 'i'
], (...and so on)
];
```

*note, this isn't the real value of the constants*

So 'value_3' originally wasn't part of the array, and I included them and updated the array later on. I used `php artisan config:clear` after the updated.

Now, I can access basically all the values of the constants, including the new `'value_3'` index, except for one constant. So for example I can get the value of `'constant_1' => 'value_3'` as well as `'constant_2' => 'value_3'` but for some reason, `constant_3` does not have a `'value_3'` even though I included it.

When I try to print it on the console, it's blank. But for the rest of the constants in the array, they all have that `'value_3'`. I tried the `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` I also tried restarting my local server and still that `'constant_3'` doesn't have that `'value_3'`. I can even get the first 2 values of `'constant_3'` and it's weird that the 3rd one is just blank.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I can't seem to find a similar problem anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to print all - `dd(config('constants'))`?

Comment: are you trying to get these values in the web interface or are you using tinker or something?

Comment: @SougataBose yes I have. All constants have a 'value_3' except for this certain 'constant_3'.

Comment: @lagbox these values will not be displayed. They're mainly accessed for the backend

Comment: how are you serving this at the moment? webserver or artisan serve?

Comment: @lagbox artisan serve

Comment: are you restarting artisan serve after that change? checking all bases just in case

Comment: @lagbox at first I didn't since the changes were reflected for the other constants but when I noticed that THAT certain 'constant_3' didn't have 'value_3', I tried to restart the server again but I had no luck. The rest of the constants were all good.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan cache:clear` see if this works.

Edit: If its still not working try all clear commands and restart server.

```
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan view:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan config:clear
```

and restart server.

Comment: `cache:clear` is for the cache store, it has nothing to do with the configuration cache

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php artisan config:cache
```

For clearing config cache.

Comment: this is for caching the config .. it just happens to clear it first

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "included them and updated the array later on" ? Don't include files manually in lavarel. If you need to update config values in runtime, use Config::set instead.

Comment: I meant I added the changes in the code. I didn't add any new files.

Comment: Mayby there is a typo or some unprintable chars in 'value_3'. good luck

Answer (score -1):

Please try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: `cache:clear` is for the cache store, it has nothing to do with the configuration cache